# C# -Mono (platform independence)

Tags: c#, mono

I'm very newbie to Ubuntu OS and I have my solution developed in visual studio 2008. 
I want my application to run in both windows and Linux(ubuntu). 
I've few questions in my mind.

1. Does mono support visual debugger .
2. If I start development  using
   mono.Is it possible to run  same in
   .net framework (windows) ?? or do I
   need to write the NSI script to
   download the libraries during
   installation from internet and
   install.
3. What is the best way to
   achieve platform independence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Mono has a debugger - see [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Assuming you don't use any Mono-specific libraries, or ship them alongside your app, it should just work in Windows against the Microsoft .NET implementation - although of course you'd want to test it.

A lot of achieving platform independence is a matter of the libraries you use: make sure whatever you want to call is either already available in both platforms or can be shipped alongside your app. Beyond that, there are obvious things like not assuming a particular path/directory separator, potentially not assuming a particular endianness (although that's rarely an issue in C# in my experience) - and regular testing, both manual and automated as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Mono add-in for Visual Studio that warns you when building your app if you use something that Mono doesn't support yet.

Don't remember the name, thought.

Comment: It's called MoMA (Mono Migration Analyzer), see http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA.